# Iterating through a dataset using CURSOR

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, cursor, iteration

I am iterating through a dataset using a cursor, checking the value of specific columns (`Myfield`) of each record one by one. I am aware that this is contrary to how SQL can analyse a dataset, but I have to use this method in this case.

Is it possible to write a condition that would check the value of a defined column? Something like

```
If Myfield = 0 
    @number = @number + 1
ELSE 
    @number = @number + 2
```

I have defined the cursor like this:

```
SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR 
                    SELECT * FROM Table1
```

but apparently this is not sufficient for T-SQL - it throws the error

> Invalid column name...

Comment: Hint: Part of the solution may involve a [`case`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx ) _expression_ (not _statement_), e.g. `set @Foo += case when @Bar = 0 then 1 else 2 end;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the cursor for the desired result set and declare variables for each field in the row you wish to compare.

```
DECLARE @myField AS INT

DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT compareField FROM Table1

OPEN my_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor   
INTO @myField  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
    If @myField = 0 THEN
         --do something--
    ELSE 
         --do something else--
    END IF

    FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor
    INTO @myField
END

CLOSE my_cursor
DEALLOCATE my_cursor
```